# Вернуть значение из метода не прерывая его

Tags: java

Я делаю текстового бота на Java и мне хочется, чтобы код был красивым и независящим друг от друга. Мне хочется чтобы методы логики и методы вывода (в консоль или в телеграм) были разделены. Как я могу это реализовать?

Comment: Обычно это реализовывается через интерфейсы. В Java они помогают разделять код и независимо работать над имплементациями

Comment: @maklas как конкретно это сделать? Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Если я правильно понял, вам нужен интерфейс для вывода информации. Например `interface IMessageConsumer` с несколькими методами, опять же, в качестве примера: `printMessage(msg, source)`, `showAlert(msg)`. И конкретная имплементация которая будет выводить данные сообщения в телеграм/консоль. Таким образом ваша "бизнесс-логика" не будет знать о телеграме или консоли. Ей нужно знать только что есть какой-то `IMessageConsumer` который будет ответственен за вывод информации юзеру.

Answer (score 1):

Стоит посмотреть на способы разделения логики и представления такие, как [MVC](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller).